# Dispatching event for radio button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This is my code:

```
 jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#s_method_flatrate_flatrate").click();
    var firstSelectOption = document.querySelector('#s_method_flatrate_flatrate');
    firstSelectOption.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});
```

This is the element I am trying to dispatch:

```
<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="flatrate_flatrate" id="s_method_flatrate_flatrate" class="radio">
```

I am trying to select the radio button which works, but the action that lies behind it is not triggered. I logged the `firstSelectOption` var and its the correct element. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do and what is the action that has to be triggered? Your code seems to do everything that you describe.

Comment: Was the functionality you want to trigger bound via jQuery as well? If so, you should rather use https://api.jquery.com/trigger/ to begin with.

Comment: having the same issue using vanilla JS,  any solution? the dispatching of a change event or a click event seems to have  no effect on my  Radio btn :(